# Gradle error in Android Studio 1.4

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting an error while I compile, build, or start Android Studio 1.4. Actually, I removed my computer's temp files and registry clean using Cleaner software. After i start Android Studio every app getting this error while compile project. the error message look like as below

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean]
Error:Could not load compiled classes for initialization script 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo2.gradle' from cache. Expected class file C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\2.4\scripts\asLocalRepo2_497u80p42kjt36hnn4qq8ljon\InitScript\initscript\classes\asLocalRepo2_497u80p42kjt36hnn4qq8ljon.class does not exist.
> asLocalRepo2_497u80p42kjt36hnn4qq8ljon
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 0.717 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Kindldy please anyone suggest me whats problem here. and how to resolve it.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Did you try to reinstall android studio entirely?

Comment: Nop, I not reinstalled android studio

Answer (score 4):

finally i solved error.

I just delete `.gradle` folder from user folder amd start new project, It will re download or re create `gradle` file.

That's it.